Adding new reference to any item in array affects behaviour of the array
I've seen many questions about this (one of them here)
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($a as &$v) { }
foreach ($a as $v) { }

print_r($a);

and I get the answers, you shouldn't be recycling the $v variable name. But..!
Can someone explain to me why this code
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($a as &$v) { }

var_dump($a);

prints this (note that the last element is a reference)?
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  &string(1) "d"
}

I expect it to be just a value, only $v should be a reference.
In other words, I'm dealing with the same behaviour as described (and well documented) in the quoted question, although I'm not reusing $v variable incorrectly.

And in another words, when I call unset($v) after the foreach, it also changes $a[3] to be just a value and not a reference. Why? $a is an array of values the whole time, isn't it?

I think the linked answer has explained your question well.

@shingo Yes, it answers that $v is a reference to $a[3] even after the foreach finished. But it doesn't answer why $a[3] itself is a reference.

I think the & is there because that value in the array is still reference by $v. If you unset $v it disappears. See: https://3v4l.org/eiAva In other words: $a[3] is not a reference, see: https://3v4l.org/mnNIk

@Vali, does this make it a little clearer what's going on? https://3v4l.org/2VZYG

@Vali, you can chech this collection of questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-guide-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php-php-syntax and PHP's References Explained page.

Well, @shingo the warning really mentions this (very briefly) but the example below doesn't reflect it, it only reflects reusing of $v issue, which is expected. @KIKOSoftware The & is not there only because it's still referenced by $v, it really is a reference. When I don't unset $v and call for example something like appendLetter($a, 'z') which to each item internally (appendLetter accepts first param by-val), $a becames ['a', 'b', 'c', 'dz'], which is unexpected and not well documented.

@Vali, because you've referenced the most common canonical answer along with the manual and you still have questions, I think it is worth reading some of the deeper dives. Personally I think this one explains it in the easiest to read manner, however this one goes very deep and even talks about "shenanigans".

@ChrisHaas Oh god, you shook me. So creating completely new variable and assigning a reference to any item of an pre-existing array to it affects the array. That's really stupid.

But @shingo once again was right, it's documented here (find 'Note, however, that references inside arrays are potentially dangerous.', which describes it not as clearly, but it does).

@Vali, would this shake you? https://3v4l.org/DsDdm. It is another version of two variables pointing to the same location. Also, just for fun: https://3v4l.org/03gTY

@ChrisHaas The first one is the same as with the array. And the second one doesn't shake me. But it's fun what this conversation became :D

However, thanks everyone for comments. Now I get how PHP works with references to array items. But for me it's not expected even so. I think one shouldn't need to dive so deep to understand something which seems to be so simple. It's more like I should expect the unexpected now.

Perhaps another way of looking at it: https://3v4l.org/ksZCp ? As you can see the reference jumps from item to item in the array as the iteration of the loop moves on. It's a reference because you assign a reference to it during the loop. The whole point of references is that they are a shared pointer to one single item in memory. As you loop, the reference, via $v is moved on to be shared with a different item in the array. Does that make sense? You say you're still finding it unexpected, but it's not clear why you still feel that way, specifically.

@Vali, one last one: https://3v4l.org/bE7VZ. As to your comment about the deep dive, I get it, and there's a 20 year old bug report with a lot of people that agree with you. But overall I think that the tl;dr is that "references are an advanced featured", and with that comes some potentially unexpected things.

@ADyson It feels strange to me, that this code 3v4l.org/uB6Pa changes the content of the array, but just one item of it, just because some seemingly irrelevant $v refers to "random" index of it. What I consider expected is that when I initiated $a as an array of strings (not references), I pass it to the function by-val, and I loop over a local copy of $a, it doesn't affect $a no matter how many other variables are referencing values of $a.

but just one item of it, just because some seemingly irrelevant $v...it's not irrelevant. $v is assigned to be the next item from the array, every time the loop runs. Therefore if you make $v a reference, it will be shared with the copy of the item which is inside the array. Next time the loop iterates, $v is moved to point to the next array item, so that becomes the item which is shared in the array. Hence why I gave you an example showing how  the reference moves from item to item with each run of the loop

I can appreciate your confusion, as I've run into this issue in my own programming. Intuitively we think of the iteration variable as being local to the loop, but PHP doesn't have block scoping. So $v doesn't stop being a reference to the array element when the loop ends and you use it as the iteration variable in the second loop. It's easier to see what's happening if you convert the foreach loop to a for loop.

I loop over a local copy of $a...that's not what happens. PHP doesn't make a copy of the array just for the purpose of looping through it. And this isn't really about $a, it's about &$v and its link to the original items inside the array

@ADyson did you see that code I linked in my last comment? I'm not moving &$v using iterations. And I don't expect PHP to make a copy of array for looping it, but a  (lazy) copy for passing it to a function. And I pass $a to the function, I do nothing with &$v.

I'm not moving &$v using iterations...yes you are. What do you think foreach does? It loops over the array. $v gets reassigned every time it loops (as I showed). Just because you didn't use that value inside the loop doesn't mean that process isn't still happening. And as Barmar notes, since PHP doesn't limit loop variables to have scope only within the loop then, after the loop finisheds, the reference still exists as a reference to the last item in the array that it looped over.

but a (lazy) copy for passing it to a function. And I pass $a to the function, I do nothing with &$v. Not sure what you mean? You aren't passing anything to any functions in your code apart from var_dump, but that just echoes the current data in the variable you pass in - and a "lazy copy" of that would still include any references, because they are shared - that being the whole point of referennces. So in other words if  you don't want the shared behaviour, don't use a reference!

However, I'm more or less at piece with the situation where lot of people see this as a bug, lot of people don't, and we all just have to live with it.

Ok. To me though it's not a bug, it's just how PHP's variable scoping works. I think it's fairly well-described online. You might argue it ought not to work like that, but that's a language design issue I'd  say. A bug is where it doesn't behave as intended. As far as I know it behaves as intended.

@ADyson posting again the link to the code I'm talking about 3v4l.org/uB6Pa

@Vali, we can remove the foreach from this discussion if it helps, too: https://3v4l.org/5WPsX

@ChrisHaas Yes, it makes even less sense that way :D Or same but it's more clear what I ment.

@Vali sorry I thought you were referring to the code in your original question. But the function makes no difference there. A reference is still shared, no matter how many places you pass it around to.

@Vali I think Chris' last link should make it easier to understand, surely. $a is copied into the function by value, except that the reference in index 2 within it is still a reference pointing to the same location in memory as in the original copy of $a, and therefore updating one of those also updates the other.

@ADyson I can understand it. I just find it unexpected :) I intensionally didn't change index 2 to be a reference, it happened behind my back. I initiated index 2 to be a string. So for me it should be done just one or the other way: 1) PHP array always behaves as an array of references, so appendZ should affect all items, or 2) PHP array always behaves as an array of (in this example) strings (except I explicitly say otherwise) and so it shouldn't be affected by $v pointing to one of those strings, so appendZ should affect none of the items. Current behaviour seems inconsistent to me.

Reformulation of the previous: From outside it seems like on the $v = &$a[2]; line PHP rips out the value 'c', moves it somewhere else in the memory and puts a reference to it into the original array under index 2. That's probably a definition for so called 'shared' references. But does PHP documentation even mention this term? And why doesn't it work like $a[1] is also 'shared' but only once (not twice like $a[2] with $v)? // sorry for that bad explanation

Or if this is expected, I'd also expect output of $a = 1; $b = &$a; $c = $a; $c++; echo $a; to be '2', that would also be consistent ($a would also behave like a 'shared' reference like $a[2] behaved in previous examples).

I'll point to one more bit of documentation about references. "People will commonly say that “$b is a reference to $a”. However, this is not quite correct, in that references in PHP have no concept of directionality. After $b =& $a, both $a and $b reference a common value, and neither of the variables is privileged in any way." They further go on to arrays explaining why this happens but do include the statement "Intuitively this behavior is wrong".

why doesn't it work like $a[1] is also 'shared' but only once...it's not clear what you mean by this, tbh. Can you clarify?

I'd also expect output of $a = 1; $b = &$a; $c = $a; $c++; echo $a; to be '2'...no, because you didn't make $c a reference to $a. Do that, and it behaves as you describe: https://3v4l.org/4llr7

This is not a good/helpful question title.

Let's close this conversation. I'm now enlightened that PHP references were made unintuitive (thanks for that) and we're getting nowere further with this :) I appreciate your time!
